# php preg_match regex split enty input spaces keywords to multiple search

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Actually I am doing the search in this way:

```
function myFun($data, $b){
    foreach ($b as $key){
        if(preg_match("/$data/i",$key->description)){
            echo 'found :'.$key->description;
        }
    }
}

if(isset($_GET["s"]) && !empty($_GET["s"]) ){
    myFun($_GET["s"], $b);
}
```

So if I search "er", I can match "light**er**", "p**er**imeter", "qu**er**y" etc.

But If I would to search "er nd", I would like to do a multiple search to match for example:
"light**er**", "qu**er**y", "int**er**national", "ba**nd**s", "bi**nd**", "se**nd**ing"

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the space in `er nd` by a pipe to obtain: `er|nd`,:

```
function myFun($data, $b) {

    // add this line
    $data = str_replace(' ', '|', $data);

    foreach ($b as $key){
        if(preg_match("/$data/i",$key->description)){
            echo 'found :'.$key->description;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried? `/$data$/i`

`$` for the end of the subject

Answer (score 0):

You have two option:

- do not search for "er nd". Split the string in "er" and "nd", then search them.
- use regular expression "(er|nd)" (check PHP syntax for regexp)

Comment: Grazie dell'aiuto Federico :) Più uno per te